How to properly render `headerLeft` in a custom `Header` component?
Inside a custom Header component, if I try to render the headerLeft from options by calling it as a normal function, useNavigation inside the headerLeft returns the wrong navigator.
navigation.goBack() goes back in the wrong navigator.
const Header = ({
  navigation,
  options: { headerLeft = HeaderLeft, headerTintColor, headerBackTitle },
}: NativeStackHeaderProps) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {headerLeft({
        canGoBack: navigation.canGoBack(),
        tintColor: headerTintColor,
        label: headerBackTitle,
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const HeaderLeft = (props: HeaderBackButtonProps) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <Button title={'back'} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />;
};

const MyNavigator = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyNavigator.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        header: Header,
      }}
    >
      <MyNavigator.Screen name={'Test'} component={() => null} />
    </MyNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};



If I modify my Header component like so, it works fine but I get type errors:
return (
    <View>
      <HeaderLeft {...{
        canGoBack: navigation.canGoBack(),
        tintColor: headerTintColor,
        label: headerBackTitle,
      }} />
    </View>
  );


I believe the issue is caused by calling the headerLeft as a function instead of rendering it as a React Component
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component

But the hooks that are in Counter [HeaderLeft] will be associated with the App component instance, because there is no Counter component instance.

What is the proper way of fixing this?
Sandbox: https://snack.expo.dev/@simon.tran/react-navigation-bug
To reproduce:

Press "Go to screen2"
Press "Go to test2"


Pressing "RootNavigator back" navigates back in RootNavigator (Back to "screen1")
Pressing "MyNavigator back" navigates back in "MyNavigator" (Back to "screen1>test")

